# .JSON object including to a .ejs file

Tags: node.js, json, express, ejs

I am working on a website project - I am using nodeJs, express.js and ejs - but I had encountered a problem with rendering and displaying a text stored in a .JSON file. My goal is to make more .json files with different languages, which I would then render based on the requested URL. But for simplicity the structure of my program looks kinda like this:

```
javascript
//---text.json---
{
  "text1" : "My first text",
  "text2" : "My second text"
}

//---layout.ejs---
<body>
  <%- include('../path/partials/header.ejs') %>
  <%- body %>
  <%- include('../path/paritals/footer.ejs') %>
</body>

//---index.ejs---
<%= main_text.text1 %>
<%= main_text.text2 %>

//---header.ejs---
<%= header_text.text1 %>
<%= header_text.text2 %>

//---router: index.js---
const text = require('../my_path_to_json_file/text.json')
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render("index", {main_text: text, header_text: text}
})
```

When I try to run the code on a localhost, everything gets displayed properly. The result, which I had expected, looks like this:

```
My first text
My second text
My first text
My second text
```

The problem comes, when I try to upload the code on an actual server, and go live with it. What I get then is this:

```
My first text  <-
My second text <- this is the header part of the website
My first text
```

For some reason, which I could not find so far, the program just omits every other .JSON text after the first. (If I would add for e. "my third text", it would had been omitted too).
I would get it, if it would just display the first .json variable, but the weird thing is, that it displays everything correctly in the header part, and when I do run the program on localHost.
I was wondering, if it could have something to do with the `<%- body %>` tag because the header is added to the layout as `include('../path/header.ejs')`. I am not an expert in this field, so could it be caused by this?
Does anybody please have an idea what could I be doing wrong, or some other suggestions of how it could be done better? Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: First investigation maybe checking for different Node versions. What is your Node's server version?

Comment: @pierpy, I have checked the server node version which was just (10), while my computer run 18. After updating that, the problem disappeared. Thank you very much for your help!